# Python, Pyqt5 Como puedo extraer valores de una celda Qtable widget para realizar una operacion y ponerlo en otra celda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Como puedo extraer de una celda en Qtable Widget ya que al usar

> self.table.item(x,x)

o

> self.table.takeitem(x,x)

no me funciona correctamente.. ya que no toma un String o un int 
y cuando madno a imprimir el Type no me retorna una variable sino

> PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x0314C970

Solo necesito eso para realizar algunas operaciones matematicas y tomar los datos de la tabla...

Gracias de Antemano.

ya estoy que vuel a Tkinter ya que Qt aparece muy poca documentacion con respecto a esto, y ps si saben de alguna pagina web que pueda servir para soporte y funciones de usar los widget. se lo agradeceria

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5 import QtCore



class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    self.title = "LuMat Uncertainty"
    self.top = 200
    self.left = 400
    self.width = 1020
    self.height = 640
    self.iconName = "icon.png"
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.iconName))
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    self.table_widget = CalUncert(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.table_widget)




    self.show()


class CalUncert(QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent):
    super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
    self.tabs = QTabWidget()
    self.tab1 = QWidget()
    self.tab2 = QWidget()
    self.Tabsimple = QWidget()
    self.GroupS= QWidget()
    self.tabs.resize(780, 480)

    # Agregar pestañas

    #self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Calculo Simple")

    self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Calculo Simple")
    self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Calculo Combinado")

    #Primera Pestaña


    self.tab1.layout = QGridLayout(self)
    self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1.layout)


    self.button = QPushButton("Calcular", self)
    self.button.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 111, 50))
    self.button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("signs.png"))
    self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
    self.button.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Atlanta", 10))
    self.button.setMinimumHeight(40)
    self.button.setToolTip("Calcular incetidumbre")



    self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.button,4,1)




    #Columna 1 Grupo 1

    self.Group1 = QGroupBox(self)
    self.Group1.setTitle("UUT")
    self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.Group1, 1,0)

    self.gridGroup1 = QGridLayout(self)
    self.Group1.setLayout(self.gridGroup1)

    self.valors = QLineEdit(self)
    self.valors.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Atlanta", 10))
    self.valors.setPlaceholderText("Insert Value")
    self.valors.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.valors.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
    self.valors.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
    self.gridGroup1.addWidget(self.valors, 1, 1)

    self.valorsL = QLabel("Valor UUT", self)
    self.valorsL.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Atlanta", 12))
    self.gridGroup1.addWidget(self.valorsL, 1, 0)

    self.tolens = QLineEdit(self)
    self.tolens.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Atlanta", 10))
    self.tolens.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
    self.tolens.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
    self.tolens.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.gridGroup1.addWidget(self.tolens, 2, 1)

    self.tolensL = QLabel("Tol. UUT fixed", self)
    self.tolensL.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Atlanta", 12))
    self.gridGroup1.addWidget(self.tolensL, 2, 0)

    self.table = QTableWidget(self)
    self.table.setRowCount(5)
    self.table.setColumnCount(4)
    # self.table.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight|Qt.AlignBottom)

    self.table.setColumnWidth(0, 250)
    self.table.setColumnWidth(3, 200)

    self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["---", "Punto Evaluado", " TUR ", "Exp. Uncertainty "])

    self.tab1.layout.addWidget(self.table, 5, 0, 1, 2)

    # Agregar pestañas al widget
    self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)
    self.setLayout(self.layout)





App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método que debes usar es  `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.item(row, column)`, ten en cuenta uqe `takeitem` remueve el item de la tabla, aunque sin eliminarlo.

Efectivamente, tal como su nombre indica se retorna una referencia al item de la tabla en esa celda si hay uno o `None` en caso contrario. Es decir, retorna una instancia de `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem`.

Lo que te falta por hacer es obtener el texto del item con su método `text` y convertirlo a `int`, `float` o lo que sea para operar con él.

```
valor = float(self.table.item(fila, columna).text())
```

Si no éstas seguro de que existe un item en esa posición, debes validar que no se retorne `None` antes de aplicar el método `text`. Lo mismo si no es seguro que contenga una cadena convertible a `int`, `float` o el tipo que sea.